# Update Destination Spreadsheet if the reference cell is blank

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code which updates the destination spreadsheet based on column A and column header

```
function updateShadowSKU() {
  var source      = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var destRange   = SpreadsheetApp.openById('104t29KUBGvglxmU-ILN0ntiNnZDkAkA4Lkm5jRoLJxk').getSheetByName('Sheet1').getDataRange();
  var destValues  = destRange.getValues();
  var destHeaders = destValues[0];
  var destIds     = destValues.map(e=>e[0]);
  var values      = source.getDataRange().getValues().map(e=>e.filter((f,i)=>!i||i>8));
  var colMap      = values[0].map(e=>destHeaders.indexOf(e));
  Logger.log(colMap);
  values = values.map((e,i,arr)=>e.map((f,j)=>[e[0],colMap[j],f,i,j])).flat().filter(e=>e[0]&&e[1]&&e[2]&&e[3]&&e[4]);
  Logger.log(values);
  if(!values.length){Logger.log('No Changes to make');return}
  values = values.map(e=>[destIds.indexOf(e[0]),e[1],e[2]]);
  
  Logger.log(values.length +' changes to make');
  Logger.log(values);

  values.forEach(function (e){try{destValues[e[0]][e[1]]=e[2]}catch(err){}});
  destRange.setValues(destValues);
}
```

This script updates everything from the source sheet regardless if the data has been updated already or not and this causes slowness on the spreadsheet (updating about 50k cells)

my data structure is something like this, the red box (columns B to G) comes from the database, it tells if the item has already update or not

[image]

now, what I really want to happen is to push the data from columns I to N to destination spreadsheet IF the corresponding columns (B to G) is empty

example:

Cell I2 will be excluded since there is data in cell B2.

Cell J2 will be included since there is no data in cell C2

sample spreadsheet:

source: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O_M2g-dh5zG71OYNb_QOX3dzvhzYJxQgsH0EEzh8njQ/edit#gid=0

destination: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/104t29KUBGvglxmU-ILN0ntiNnZDkAkA4Lkm5jRoLJxk/edit#gid=0

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `now, what I really want to happen is to push the data from columns I to N to destination spreadsheet IF the corresponding columns (B to G) is empty example: Cell I2 will be excluded since there is data in cell B2. Cell J2 will be included since there is no data in cell C2`. So, I cannot understand your expected result. Can I ask you about the detail of your expected result?

Comment: Hello, to make it simple, I just want to push data if the columns matching columns I to N is blank. example:

Cell I2 will be excluded since there is data in cell B2.

Cell J2 will be included since there is no data in cell C2

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. In this case, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? From this, I would like to try to understand your question. Can you provide it?

Comment: Dint be sorry, i think i just can't explain ot simpler. The data are already in the post, and the output would be the same as my existing code. What I want to change is the process, since the existing code pushes the data to the destination regardless if that specific data has been forwarded before. That red box in the image shows what data has been updated in the destination and the code should ignore it if it has data, like if item1 in store1 has already data, the code should ignore it

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, from `i think i just can't explain ot simpler.`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: So, columns B to G is from the destination, it is the data that has been updated before. It is my basis on which store should have updated next.

Comment: Columns I to N is the data that needs to be forwarded to the destination, but over time, the data is being updated near 100% and my code captures all data in I to N regardless if it is already in the destination or not. What I want is, before the code forwards the data to the destination, it should check if the data in I to N is already in B to G, if yes, the code should exclude that

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to support you. I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251022/discussion-between-yae-and-tanaike).

Comment: I have explain it further in the chat

Comment: @Tanaike I have edited the source sheet, I hope this clears things out: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O_M2g-dh5zG71OYNb_QOX3dzvhzYJxQgsH0EEzh8njQ/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer.

added this code block to check the destination cell if it has data on it or not, and if it has data, it will just skip that cell

```js
values.forEach(function (e){
   try{
    if(destValues[e[0]][e[1]]==""){
       destValues[e[0]][e[1]]=e[2];
    }
```

the final code will be something like this one:

```js
function updateShadowSKU() {
  var source      = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var destRange   = SpreadsheetApp.openById('104t29KUBGvglxmU-ILN0ntiNnZDkAkA4Lkm5jRoLJxk').getSheetByName('Sheet1').getDataRange();
  var destValues  = destRange.getValues();
  var destHeaders = destValues[0];
  var destIds     = destValues.map(e=>e[0]);
  var values      = source.getDataRange().getValues().map(e=>e.filter((f,i)=>!i||i>8));
  var colMap      = values[0].map(e=>destHeaders.indexOf(e));
  Logger.log(colMap);
  values = values.map((e,i,arr)=>e.map((f,j)=>[e[0],colMap[j],f,i,j])).flat().filter(e=>e[0]&&e[1]&&e[2]&&e[3]&&e[4]);
  Logger.log(values);
  if(!values.length){Logger.log('No Changes to make');return}
  values = values.map(e=>[destIds.indexOf(e[0]),e[1],e[2]]);
  
  Logger.log(values.length +' changes to make');
  Logger.log(values);

  values.forEach(function (e){
   try{
    if(destValues[e[0]][e[1]]==""){
       destValues[e[0]][e[1]]=e[2];
    }catch(err){}});
  destRange.setValues(destValues);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in destination file you can use query function as the following:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ur spreed sheet id","Sheet1!A1:G"),"select * 
where Col1 is not null and Col2 is not null and Col3 is not null 
and Col4 is not null and Col5 is not null and Col6 is not null and 
Col7 is not null",1)
```

if you want a specific column even if it is blank you can remove it from (where) statement.
Note that this query returns an array, so make sure there is no override.

Comment: we need it to be in script so we can just click the button, since importrange always resulted in error especially in large dataset